# "Mi sono ingarbugliata": sto usando "ingarbugliare" in modo corretto?

Tags: word-meaning, word-usage, verbs, word-choice

Ultimamente, ho qualche volta usato l'espressione "mi sono ingarbugliata" (non saprei dire dove né perché) per cercare di trasmettere l'idea che sono stata colta da una grande confusione. Per esempio, mi sono talmente confusa su qualche argomento, non per nervosismo, semplicemente per confusione delle idee, che ho finito per spiegarlo in modo assolutamente illogico. O ho cercato di risolvere un problema (matematico o in cui devo usare la matematica), ma ho scelto delle strategie non molto intelligenti che mi hanno portata a delle espressioni complicatissime, per cui ho deciso di buttare nel cestino tutto il lavoro fatto e ricominciare da capo. O ho scritto una domanda su un sito SE, ma poi mi sono accorta di aver spiegato parecchi fatti non veri, per cui ho deciso di cancellarla.

Mi riferisco a questo tipo di cose. In castigliano direi "me he hecho un lío", in catalano "m'he fet un embolic" e in inglese, non sono del tutto sicura, ma credo sarebbe "I've got into a muddle".

Comunque, non sono certa che il verbo "ingarbugliarsi" possa essere usato con questo significato.

Ho dato un'occhiata alle voci "ingarbugliare" del [vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ingarbugliare) e del [*Grande dizionario della lingua italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI07/00001023.jpg) e ho visto che questo verbo si adopera in senso figurato in frasi come

> la questione si ingarbuglia

oppure

> Come  mi  mettevo  davanti  la  carta  e 
>   intraprendevo di scrivere, la faccenda si ingarbugliava. O il  foglio  si  riempiva  di  cancellature,  oppure  tiravo diritto  per  una  pagina  o  due  e  poi  mi  accorgevo  di  aver 
>   ammucchiato  una  quantità di frasi  generiche  e  senza concretezza (Moravia).

Mi sono anche accorta che "ingarbugliato" può essere utilizzato come aggettivo in senso figurato col significato di "confuso", come in questo esempio:

> Nacque  a  questo punto una discussione ingarbugliatissima (Moravia).

Tuttavia, non ho visto in modo esplicito che "ingarbugliarsi" possa voler dire "essere colto da una grande confusione". Per questa ragione vi chiedo: posso usare questo verbo per esprimere questo significato? E, se non fosse così, quale verbo o espressione potrei utilizzare?

Comment: C'è anche un altro significato, che secondo me è pure predominante rispetto alla confusione: *complicazione*. Naturalmente è opinione mia e solo mia. E poi, *ingarbugliarsi* implica una specie di volontà, un agire su sé stessi, che però è un po' diverso da *confondersi*.

Comment: Un contesto tipico per ingarbugliarsi autoreferenziale è quando uno per nervosismo verbalizza in modo non logico (esami, colloqui di lavoro)

Comment: Per esprimere una grande confusione mi sembra più adeguato "andare in tilt" (lingua parlata).

Comment: @charo Qui trovi la definizione di quanto sembra esserti sfuggito nelle tue ricerche: https://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/I/ingarbugliare.shtml Google helps ;-)

Comment: Tra l'altro  la risposta alla tua domanda la trovi sul sito che linki 2. Come intr. pron., confondersi, intricarsi e, in senso fig., complicarsi: i fili si sono ingarbugliati; la questione si ingarbuglia, si fa più difficile; con altro uso fig., ma poco com., di persona, impappinarsi, confondersi nel parlare: per l’emozione si è ingarbugliato e non è più riuscito ad andare avanti.

Comment: Ma se "ingarbugliato" significasse "essere colto da una grande confusione", lo troveresti nei dizionari. Non è perché tu attribuisci un  tuo senso a una parola (che hai usato senza sapere perché dove o quando) che i dizionari debbano registrarlo...

Comment: Benissimo, il dizionario che ti ho citato sopra ti risponde. Il senso dei miei commenti era che "essere colto da grande confusione" non è il significato di ingarburgliarsi, ma la sua causa.

Comment: Grazie per indicarmi il Sabatini Coletti, @Nico, ma continuo a non sapere quale sia
la risposta alla mia domanda. Non sono del tutto sicura che "queste chiacchiere mi ingarbugliano" sia lo stesso di "mi sono ingarbugliata a causa di queste chiacchiere". Forse sì, ma non ho le idee chiare.

Comment: @Charo puoi essere sicura, applicando l'analisi logica, che quelle due frasi hanno lo stesso identico significato, espresse però in tempi diversi e con costruzioni diverse.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica: Quelle due frasi hanno significati simili, ma non è certo l'analisi logica a dirlo: basta che pensi a “Gino mi spara” e “mi sono sparata a causa di Gino”, che hanno rispettivamente la stessa struttura logica di quelle frasi, ma hanno due significati ben diversi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Riporto a seguire la definizione del verbo *ingarbugliare* tratta da *Lo Zingarelli* (edizione 2009).

> **Ingarbugliare** [comp. di in- e garbuglio; 1481] v. tr. (io ingarbuglio)
>
> A
>
> 1. Mescolare disordinatamente più cose: *i. i fili di un gomitolo di lana; i. i conti*. **sin.**. Aggrovigliare, intricare, imbrogliare | (**fig.**) Complicare, intralciare.
> 2. (**fig., lett.**) Raggirare | (**lett.**) Disorientare: *i. qualcu. con lunghi discorsi*.
>
> B
>
> **ingarbugliarsi** v. intr. pron.
>
> 1. Aggrovigliarsi, intricarsi: *la catena dell'ancora si è ingarbugliata attorno a un pilone* | (**fig.**) Complicarsi: *la situazione s'ingarbuglia*.
> 2. (**fig**., **colloq**.) Impappinarsi: *ingarbugliarsi in un discorso difficile, all'esame*. 
>      **Sfumature** vd. impappinare

Come avrai letto trattasi di un espressione colloquiale sicché un uso in tal senso del verbo ingarbugliare può essere più o meno corretto a seconda del contesto in cui è adoprato. Dunque la questione può spostarsi ora su un piano puramente semantico-etimologico. Come avrai letto tale verbo è derivato dalla composizione del sostantivo garbuglio e della preposizione "in" sicché il significato del verbo ingarbugliare è direttamente determinato da quello del sostantivo "garbuglio" che intende indicare un *intreccio complicato o disordinato* -vd. *Lo Zingarelli* (edizione 2009). Allora *ingarbugliare* assumerebbe il significato di *essere in un garbuglio*, ovvero  *trovarsi in una situazione alquanto complicata*, sicché si comprende che per "trasposizione" l'uso pronominale di tale verbo può certo assumere il significato di *essersi ficcato in un garbuglio*.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE e grazie della risposta. Tuttavia, "impappinarsi" che appare nella voce dello Zingarelli che hai citato, non ha a che vedere con "parlare"? E poi ho visto in [Sinonimi e Contrari del Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/impappinarsi_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) che "ingarbugliarsi" appare marcato come *non com.* Dovrei dunque concludere che si tratta di un uso non comune di questo verbo?

Comment: Imppappinarsi ha il significato di *confondersi nel parlare* e Lo Zingarelli rimanda alla consultazione di tale verbo perché ci si può ingarbugliare anche colle parole oltre che con i ragionamenti! pensa infatti ad uno scioglilingua! Poi in proposito di quanto indicato dal Treccani debbo ahimè dire di dissentire dalla sua affermazione, poiché infatti da italiano posso asserire che spesso utilizzo tale verbo quando il caso lo consente.

Comment: Benvenuto! Ho l'impressione che ci siamo sentiti da poco su Math.SE!

Comment: +1 per "adoprato", +1 per l'ahimè sul Treccani, e ora sono rimasto senza +1.

Comment: Vedo che ti piace molto la congiunzione “sicché”. :) Toscano?

Comment: @DaG No, lucano.

Comment: @Egreg Confermo quanto ha detto

Answer (score -1):

> "ingarbugliarsi" possa voler dire "essere colto da una grande confusione"

http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/confondere

indica (tra altri significati) "riunire cose che dovrebbero stare separate". In effetti la radice della parola contiene *fondere*. Il senso principale di *confondere* è appunto sovrapporre, vedere una cosa invece di un'altra, essere sviati e attribuire a una cosa ciò che è di un'altra.

*Ingarbugliare* è diverso, non si mescolano cose diverse, si *incasinano* quelle già presenti. *Ingarbugliare* e *incasinare* sono pressoché equivalenti, registro ed età delle parole a parte.

A questo punto una persona, quando è confusa, può ingarbugliare le parole (usarle, scriverle o pronunciarle in modo errato, di ortografia/pronuncia, oppure con costruzione o significato errati).

Viceversa, quando s'ingarbuglia qualche cosa si crea confusione, direttamente *dentro* a quella cosa. Per esempio, al mio interlocutore posso "fare un discorso ingarbugliato" (in questa frase i termini sono propri, materiali); ma io non posso materialmente *ingarbugliare* il mio interlocutore - in quest'ultima frase il senso d'*ingarbugliare* è figurato, per farlo in senso materiale dovrei aprirgli la testa e scambiargli di posto i neuroni.

**Quindi la risposta alla tua domanda è NO**, con riserva. Con riserva perchè, normalmente, chi s'ingarbuglia è confuso, e chi ingarbuglia confonde (qualcun altro). Questo si riferisce ai modi riflessivi, però. Se invece c'è la volontà d'ingarbugliare, insomma lo si fa apposta, c'è anche necessità di non essere confusi, per ingarbugliare bene le cose. Difatti, c'è una frase che recita "errare è umano, ma per ingarbugliare davvero tutto ci vuole un computer" (è una perla delle Leggi di Murphy).

-- aggiornamento --

Avevo dimenticato di dare un'alternativa, come richiesto dalla domanda.

A parer mio non esiste altro modo. Per dire "sono confusa", la frase giusta è "sono confusa"; si può calcare con "sono molto confusa", "sono estremamente confusa". Altre parole, frasi o perifrasi sarebbero necessariamente diverse, per esempio "sono in confusione" "ho la testa confusa" "non capisco più niente" "non riesco a ragionare" "sono persa" "ho un vuoto mentale" "ho un casino in testa" "sragiono" "non riesco a connettere" "non trovo il bandolo della matassa" "non trovo più il cervello" "ho le farfalle in testa" "ho i pensieri incasinati" "i miei neuroni si stanno prendendo a pugni".

Comment: Grazie della risposta, @linuxfan, ma in questo momento sono molto confusa. Ho ricevuto due risposte: una dice di sì (l'unica che sia stata votata fino al momento), l'altra di no... Tu stesso hai detto in un commento che il Sabatini Colletti sembra suggerire di sì (o perlomeno è ciò quello che ho capito io). Inoltre, nota che nella domanda chiedo un verbo o espressione alternativi.

Comment: Concordo in toto (ed era in parte quello che intendevo io sopa). Se "ingarbugliato" avesse quel senso, corrisponderebbe a uno stato d'animo che si potrebbe anche rendere in forma di aggettivo in modo analogo a "oggi mi sento confuso/tormentato etc". Invece "oggi mi sento ingarbugliato" non suona.

Comment: @linuxfansaysReinstateMonica Tra l'altro questo orientamento è fallace poiché i dizionari non fanno altro che registrare seppure con ritardo quello che usano i parlanti. Non sono i dizionari a stabilire il significato di una parola, ma la frequenza con cui i parlanti la utilizzano in certi contesti...